# Copying rows from target table to source table with conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

Consider below two tables,

```
Parent Table
------------
Parentid
1
2
3
4
5
6


Child Table
-----------

Id  ParentId  Values
1     1        val1
2     2        val2
3     3        val3
```

Now i want to insert records to child table for parentid 4,5,6 with all values from Parentid 1,2,3. So child table should be like below,

```
Id    ParentId   Values
 1       1         Val1
 2       2         Val2
 3       3         Val3
 4       4         Val1
 5       5         Val2
 6       6         Val3
```

Please share SQL query for my scenario. I am using SQL server 2008, so let me know any advanced query also.

Note: In my real scenario, I have more number of records. So I don't want to hardcode any values on my insert statement.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes ,I understand. In my real scenario I need to insert records in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Parent TABLE (pid INT);
DECLARE @Child TABLE (cid INT,pid INT, value varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @Parent 
VALUES  (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6)

INSERT INTO @Child
VALUES (1,1,'a'),
       (2,2,'b')


;WITH ChildValues AS
(
    SELECT value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RandonIDs ASC) RN
    FROM (
        SELECT RAND() RandonIDs,
               value
        FROM @Child 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT RAND(),
               value
        FROM @Child 

          )
)
,MissingParentIDs AS
(
    SELECT Pid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Pid ASC) RN   
    FROM @Parent P
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT C.Pid
              FROM @Child C
              WHERE C.Pid = P.Pid) 
)
SELECT Pid,
       Value
--INTO Destination Table
FROM MissingParentIDs M
INNER JOIN ChildValues V
ON M.RN = V.RN
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are looking for something like this

```
Declare @maxPID INT = (SELECT MAX(ParentId) from child)
DECLARE @count int= 1
DECLARE @pID INT

SET @pID = @maxPID

WHILE @count <= @maxPID
BEGIN
  SET @pID = @pID + 1
  INSERT INTO child
  Values (@pID, (SELECT TOP 1 Value from Child where parentId = @count))
  set @count = @count+1
END
```

here is the sql fiddle for it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7db5d/1